# Python: Use of class methods to change data

Tags: python, object-oriented

Could you please give me some feedback on the use of class methods in this Python script?
The code retrieves time entries from the [Toggl API](https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs) and works as expected. My question is, do the methods make sense? The methods `first_api_call` and `make_subsequent_calls` change `self.data`. Is this okay or should all the changes to `self.data` be made in `retrieve_data`?

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests

today = datetime.today().date()
since = datetime(today.year, 1, 1)


class Toggl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.total_calls = None
        self.params = {
            'workspace_id': '5604761',
            'since': since,
            'until': today,
            'user_agent': 'john@doe.com',
            'page': 1,
        }

    def retrieve_data(self):
        r = self.first_api_call()
        self.total_calls = self.calculate_number_of_extra_calls_needed(r)
        self.make_subsequent_calls()

    def first_api_call(self):
        r = requests.get('https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/details',
                         params=self.params,
                         auth=('APIKEY', 'api_token'))
        r.raise_for_status()
        r = r.json()
        self.data = r['data']
        return r

    def calculate_number_of_extra_calls_needed(self, r):
        """
        Calculate the number of pages that need to be retrieved.
        The second part is True/False to round up.
        Finally minus 1 because we got the first page already.
        """
        total_calls = r['total_count'] // 50 + (r['total_count'] % 50 > 0) - 1
        return total_calls

    def make_subsequent_calls(self):
        """Make the new API calls and store the data"""
        for i in range(self.total_calls):
            self.params['page'] = self.params['page'] + 1
            r = requests.get('https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/details',
                             params=self.params,
                             auth=('APIKEY', 'api_token'))
            r.raise_for_status()
            r = r.json()
            for d in r['data']:
                self.data.append(d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    toggl = Toggl()
    toggl.retrieve_data()
    print(toggl.data)
```

Comment: In general is a good practice to have the requests.get operations on a try block, so if there is an issue on the network, or auth your program can continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be best to move

```
today = datetime.today().date()
since = datetime(today.year, 1, 1)
```

into the class's `__init__`. As it is, the code will just be run once when the module loads, whereas it would make more sense to work out the date when you construct `Toggl`.

I'd also say that having two methods for what is essentially the exact same task could be streamlined. Perhaps something like this?

```py
import math

# Default page size in the Toggl API.
PAGE_SIZE = 50

class Toggl:
    def __init__(self):
        today = datetime.today().date()
        since = datetime(today.year, 1, 1)
        self.data = []
        self.total_calls = None
        self.params = {
            'workspace_id': '5604761',
            'since': since,
            'until': today,
            'user_agent': 'john@doe.com'
        }

    def fetch_page(self, page_number):
        params = self.params
        params['page'] = page_number
        r = requests.get('https://toggl.com/reports/api/v2/details',
                         params=params,
                         auth=('APIKEY', 'api_token'))
        r.raise_for_status()
        return r.json()

    def retrieve_data(self):
        r = self.fetch_page(1)
        self.data = r['data']
        pages = self.total_pages(r['total_count'])
        for i in range(2, pages + 1):
            r = self.fetch_page(i)
            self.data += r['data']

    def total_pages(self, total_count):
        return math.ceil(total_count / PAGE_SIZE)
```

In particular, any "magic number" constants should be taken out and put at the top as constants (by convention in `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`). I tweaked the function names to be more descriptive, and replaced `first_api_call` and `make_subsequent_calls` with a function that doesn't affect the state: instead it just makes a call to fetch the required page and `retreive_data` decides what to do with it. I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with doing it as you did though, I just personally thought `fetch_page` seemed cleaner and reduced duplication.

You can simplify the calculation to work out how many pages you need using `math.ceil` as I demonstrate above too: for example 101 / 50 = 2.02, which is mapped to 3 by `math.ceil`.

To make the code even better, you could avoid storing the API key hard coded: take it as a parameter in the constructor and store it in `self`. You could also take `since` and `today` as parameters so the user can choose the range that they want to obtain.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I meant. API responses are almost always paginated. I like how you encapsulated it in the retrieval method. Great other recommendations too, I'll incorporate them all in my code. (BTW: the API keys live in environment variables, just hardcoded them to simplify the example). Thanks again, it is very much appreciated!